# How to catch null while summarizing records in EF6

Tags: entity-framework, linq

next problem with Linq/EF6 queries.

I simply like to build a sum of some decimal fields:

```
var offsetHours1 = (from os in db.TimesheetOffsets
                    where (os.EmployeeId == employeeId && os.OffsetDate <= DateTime.Today)
                    select new
                     {
                      offset = os.OffsetHours
                     }).Sum(h=>h.offset);
```

So far it works, if I have records to sum but if the query returns null or no records, I get a **System.InvalidOperationException**

Is there an elegant way to summarize records in one step, so if there are no records, 0 is returned?

Thanks, Carsten

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a quirk with the `Sum` extension method. As `OffsetHours` is a decimal, the overload of `Sum` you'll be using is `Sum(..., decimal)` which has this behaviour. To avoid it you can cast the value to a `decimal?` (nullable). With this you'll be using a different Sum that returns a nullable decimal and is OK with empty lists;

You can for example do this;

```
var offsetHours1 = (from os in db.TimesheetOffsets
                    where (os.EmployeeId == employeeId && os.OffsetDate <= DateTime.Today)
                    select os.OffsetHours)
                   .Sum(h => (decimal?)h);
```

**Edit**: 
Removed unnecessary creation of anonymous type.

Comment: Ok, thanks for explanantion. Is there perhaps a way, that sum returns 0, if there are no records to summarize?

Comment: Not without creating a condition of your own. The code I provided will be shortest way there (it's a risky business making such a claim on a forum like this :) )

Comment: don't understand what's risky?

Comment: I was referring to my own claim that my solution is the shortest form to achieve what you wanted. Somebody might suggest an alternative that looks more elegant. I have provided the answer that I like best. Hope it helps you.